# Recuperar el focus al inicio del TextField si este lo pierde en Java

Tags: java

**Foto del problema:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pregunta:**

Si el usuario hace clic 1 vez, el focus automáticamente se coloca al inicio del TextField pero, se puede hacer clic en cualquier lugar del TextField y este te deja escribir. Cómo puedo hacer que el focus siempre se coloque al inicio del TextField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método a emplear sería [setCaretPosition(int posicion)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition(int)) para colocar el cursor al inicio sería **0**

```
   MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("(###) ###-####");
   textField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
   textField.setSize(new Dimension(100,40));
```

Para validar esto mediante el evento `Focus` tendríamos que añadir un [Focuslistener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) para saber cuando se da dicho evento. *(una vez dado el evento focus se podrá desplazar al lugar que desee dentro del JFormattedTextField)*

```
   MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("(###) ###-####");
   textField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
   textField.setSize(new Dimension(100,40));
   textField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
       @Override
       public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
           System.out.println("Focus In");
           textField.setCaretPosition(0);
       }

       @Override
       public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
           System.out.println("Focus Out");
       }
   });
```

Para que **siempre** al seleccionar el  `JFormattedTextField` se coloque al inicio sería con el evento `click` , añadiendo un [mouselistener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

```
textField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            if(textField.getText().replaceAll("[()-]", "").trim().length()==0)
                textField.setCaretPosition(0);
            else
                textField.setCaretPosition(textField.getText().length());
        }
    });
```

Comment: gracias hermano, perfecto!!!. Una cosa, si el textfield tiene contenido, el focus se ubica al inicio, como lo hemos establecido, para hacer que se ubique al final seria con un IF, si el text isEmpty, ubicar foco al final?. Si el usuario desea borrar algo, el foco se le ubica al inicio.

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta . añadiendo un if adicional para ese detalle

Comment: muchas gracias Dev Joel. Te lo agradezco mucho.